# Bintray Debian Repository Creation and Upload file using API

Tags: curl, debian, bintray

I'm following the steps and answers in
[Debian repository on Bintray multiple errors and unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991329/debian-repository-on-bintray-multiple-errors-and-unexpected-behavior)

However, my Bintray Debian file upload attempt still failed with:

```
{"message":"Unable to upload files: Debian distribution, component and architecture were not found on repo and were not specified"}
```

Here is my curl command:

```
curl -T libterm-screencolor-perl_1.09-1_all.deb -umyid:mybintraykey https://api.bintray.com/content/myid/myrepo/libterm-screencolor-perl/1.09-1/pool/main/l/libterm-screencolor-perl_1.09-1_all.deb;deb_distribution=all;deb_component=main;deb_architecture=i386,amd64;override=1
```

Basically I'm getting the exact same error as 
[Debian repository on Bintray multiple errors and unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991329/debian-repository-on-bintray-multiple-errors-and-unexpected-behavior)
for the exact same reason.

So I decided to start from scratch, from creating the Bintray Debian Repository first, [via API](https://bintray.com/docs/api/#_create_repository).
Here is my code:

```
curl -umyid:mybintraykey https://api.bintray.com/repos/myid/deb -d '{"name":"deb","type":"debian","default_debian_architecture":"amd64","default_debian_distribution":"all","default_debian_component":"main","private":false,"desc":"This repo...","business_unit":"businessUnit1","labels":["label1","label2"],"gpg_sign_metadata":false,"gpg_sign_files":false,"gpg_use_owner_key":false}'
```

I got no error, but no response either. When I check from the Bintray web UI, the repository was not created. Trying to add, `"version_update_max_days" : 60` to the JSON does not help either.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Upload file:*
Your `curl` command needs quotation marks, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44991329/debian-repository-on-bintray-multiple-errors-and-unexpected-behavior/45006427?noredirect=1#comment77989146_45006427).

*Create repository:*
Your `curl` command is missing the Media type, which in this case should be  `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`. It is always good to run your `curl` command in verbose mode `-v`

Here is how your `curl` command should look like:

```
curl -umyid:mybintraykey https://api.bintray.com/repos/myid/deb -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"deb","type":"debian","default_debian_architecture":"amd64","default_debian_distribution":"all","default_debian_component":"main","private":false,"desc":"This repo...","business_unit":"businessUnit1","labels":["label1","label2"],"gpg_sign_metadata":false,"gpg_sign_files":false,"gpg_use_owner_key":false}' -v
```